# What does the "position" field in the return value of "get_survey_details" mean?

Tags: surveymonkey

When I get survey details for my survey (using the API call "get_survey_details") there is a new field, "position" which is not described in the description of for the method (https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_survey_details). In particular, position should appear as this:

data.pages[_].position

I infer that position refers to the survey page that this set of questions appear on -- but it would be good if I could confirm that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position associated with a page is always the same as the index number of the page in the pages array and represents the order of the pages in the survey design.